# SQL help to identify the Missing Data

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following COMPANY_TABLE table

```
SOURCE  UNIQUE_COMPANY_D    RECORD_STATE    SUB_COMPANY_ID  PARENT  PRIMARY_PARENT
ABC 111 Secondary   123     999 
XYZ 111 Primary     456     
YYY 222 Secondary   895     888        888
TTT 222 Primary     902                888
VVV 333 Primary     101     777        777
RRR 333 Secondary   187                777
```

IN WHERE UNIQUE_COMPANY_ID = '111' is the issue.

PRIMARY_PARENT IS NOT POPULATED, It should populate based on PARENT. If the PARENT field has Value it should Populate for both rows. if null it has to grab the value from secondary row and populate PRIMARY_PARENT Value. I have like 10 million rows where I need to find the scenarios where Parent is populated and Primary parent is not populated. based on the above criteria. (If the PARENT field has Value it should Populate for both rows. if null it has to grab the value from secondary row and populate PRIMARY_PARENT Value) I want to identify all the error records from 10 million rows.

And I created the SQL below :

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY_TABLE WHERE PARENT IS NOT NULL AND PRIMARY_PARENT IS NULL;
```

But all its showing me single row. I need something which can get me two rows in order and able to differentiate the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Differentiate the issue"? Also, are you sure the error values are all nulls and you don't need to check for blanks as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one of the conditions. You also want whenever PARENT is NULL the Value of PRIMARY_PARENT be equal to the value of PARENT in the next row. You can take care of it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, LEAD(PARENT) OVER(Order BY (SELECT NULL)) as LeadParent FROM     COMPANY_TABLE) T
WHERE PARENT IS NOT NULL AND PRIMARY_PARENT IS NULL
     OR ((PARENT IS NULL) AND LeadParent != PRIMARY_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kumar stated, you could try and test to see if the values Parent and Primary_Parent by default are NULL's or blanks.

Did you try:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY_TABLE WHERE PARENT <> '' AND PRIMARY_PARENT <> ''
```